# Ports 80 or 443(SSL) already in use! Installing Apache2.2 service failed

Tags: xampp, localhost

"Ports 80 or 443(SSL) already in use! Installing Apache2.2 service failed" I got this message while installing xampp 1.7.7 after the installation I tried running the localhost/xampp page buts its redirecting me to this page http://www.website-unavailable.com please help

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have an another web server installed and running.

Which OS do you use?